# How to use a font you imported into unity in Text Mesh Pro

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use Comfortaa in my title screen for my game, so I imported it into my assets folder, and when I tried to use it in my Text Mesh Pro it wouldn't show up, and when I tried to drag it right into the field it wouldn't let me put it there.

Comment: Try [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/use-other-fonts-in-textmesh-pro.527960/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Unity Menu, go to Window -> TexMesh Pro -> Font Asset creator, and select the font you want to convert.

Answer (score 1):

Create `Fonts` folder under assets, drag all of your fonts there. And then for each font, right click on it and apply this

[image]